# Cannot upgrade Laravel from 6 to 7 composer hangs

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, laravel-6

I'm trying to upgrade Laravel from v6 to v7. I followed the guide in the documentation, but when I run `composer update` nothing happens. I've tried waiting for hours and still nothing. Running composer in debug mode with `composer update -vvv` yields this:

```
Looking at all rules.
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #521)
```

This is my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
        "fico7489/laravel-pivot": "^3.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "google/protobuf": "v3.6.1",
        "grpc/grpc": "^1.15",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^10.0",
        "phpmentors/workflower": "1.3.*",
        "pragmarx/firewall": "^2.2",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations": "^1.1",
        "superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage": "^2.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-bcmath": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "nunomaduro/larastan": "^0.6",
        "phake/phake": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3",
        "symfony/process": "^4.5",
        "symplify/easy-coding-standard": "^4.7",
        "mnabialek/laravel-sql-logger":"2.2.8"
    },
```

I believe all the required dependencies for laravel 7 are met but I cannot get arround the composer update problem. It gives no other information and I am lost at this point. I guess some of the packages has a problem with the update but then again, nothing fails. If I bump the version of say symmfony/process to 4.1, it starts throwing errors that are comprehensive and I can fix.
I hope someone has an idea of how I can fix this, or at least point me in the right direction.
NB. This is using composer 1.10. Composer 2 is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies won't work together: Laravel v7 requires Symfony in v5, so putting `"symfony/process": "^4.5"` in the list of packages can not be resolved (especially as there is no version of Symfony matching that constraint). Remove this constraint, as `laravel/framework` already requires `symfony/process` - you don't gain anything by requiring it once more.

Next up: `phpmentors/workflower` is not yet compatible with Symfony v5, this could also cause problems.

Comment: Thanks, I did actually just find the same issues you pointed out after hours of adding and removing packages. workflower actually has a dev version that works with symfony 5, so I guess I'll be using that for now.